# Python: divide array elements that are not None

Tags: python, numpy

Please go easy on me I'm not a programmer only a med student. I'm having trouble with doing the following operation.

self.longitude is a list:
self.longitude = [None, None, 1,7,3,4,....]

```
 self.longitude = np.array(self.longitude)
    self.longitude = np.where(self.longitude is None, None, self.longitude/11930465)
```

seems easy enough but its throwing the following exception:

> ```
> File ".../Desktop/trainalysis/mysite/feed/fitparse.py", line 36, in __init__
>     self.longitude = np.where(self.longitude is None, None, self.longitude/11930465)
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'
> ```

So clearly the interpreter is still attempting the dividing the None values. So I would presume `numpy.where()` does the operation on the array first and only after would replace the conditional values?

Would someone be so kind to suggest a solid solution for doing what I want to do that doesn't involve a hack around with a loop, which seems not very performant?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: First, the arguments to the function are evaluated. One of the arguments is `self.longitude/11930465` and that fails because `self.longitude` is `None`. And even if it did not fail (if `self.longitude` was not `None`), this would not work, because it would call `numpy.where(False, None, self.longitude/11930465)`

Comment: No, self.longitude is a numpy array containing some NoneType values and some integers. Maybe I should have made that clearer

Comment: The error in that line says `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'`. Therefore, `self.longitude` is `None`.

Comment: god i checked, i must have deleted something with the parser ..... thanks, this was  confusing the heck out of me. Indeed longitude was None, I didn't even consider that thats why the whole thing threw me off so badly... awkward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following

```
self.longitude[np.where(self.longitude != None)] /= 11930465
```

This does in-place division of the not None elements of `self.longitude` by `11930465`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want to divide all the non-none values of your numpy array.
You can try to create a mask for these, then use that mask to perform operations on your array:

```
import numpy as np

longitudes = np.array([None, 1, 2, None, 5])

nonNoneMask = longitudes!=None
longitudes[nonNoneMask] /= 11930465

print(longitudes)
print(longitudes[nonNoneMask])
```

Note that i'm using `!= None` instead of `is None`. Equality operations are overloaded by numpy arrays to be performed element-wise, while the `is` would check if both sides of the operation are the same object.

Comment: If you find an answer that solves your question, you can mark it as answered for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

If `self.longtitude` contains either numbers or `None`, it is safe to use `!=`:

```
longtitude = [None,None,1,2,3,4]
longtitude = np.array(longtitude)
longtitude = longtitude[longtitude != None] / 11930465
```

Or if you wish to keep the None values:

```
longtitude[longtitude != None] =/ 11930465
```

Note that it won't be necessarily safe if it will contain other values then `None` and numbers (specifically, objects).